# How to return a value from a function and print it in the while loop in python?

Tags: python, return-value, global, function

I have the following code:

```
A = 3

def Calculation():
    global A
    B = 2 * A
    return B

print B
```

I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

How can I fix this error? What is the right code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think downvoting newcomer users is a good idea. It's better to teach them how to work SO.

Comment: please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

You example makes no sense.

Either print the return value of the function...

```py
A = 3

def Calculation():
    global A
    B = 2 * A
    return B

print Calculation()
```

Or don't use a function:

```py
A = 3
B = 2 * A
print B
```

Or globalize `B` in your function as well and call the function before printing `B`:

```py
A = 3

def Calculation():
    global A, B
    B = 2 * A

Calculation()
print B
```

---

You don't need to use the global variable `A` though, but you should pass it as argument to `Calculation` instead. Example:

```py
A = 3

def Calculation(a):
    B = 2 * A
    return B

print Calculation(A)
```

You should also use "snake-case" names for functions (all lower case, separate words with underscores "`_`").

How your code example could be written best (in my opinion) is:

```py
a = 3

def calculation(factor):
    return = 2 * factor

print calculation(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply print your function call like so ::

```
A = 3

def Calculation(a):
    B = 2 * A
    return B

print Calculation(A)
```

The reason you were getting the error that B was not defined is because your variable B is a local variable to the function Calculation. Its scope is only visible within that method.

Comment: To explain the answers here: There's this thing called "scope."  Each function has its own scope, B was defined within that scope and therefore does not exist in the parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = 3

def Calculation():
    global A
    B = 2 * A
    return B

B = Calculation()

print B
```

Comment: A = 3, defines a declaration statement, where you fix the value of A and it can be used as global variable. After this you define your method Calculation() with no parameter as input also this function will always return you B (defined inside function). In order to use method Calculation you need to call it with a return variable B = Calculation(). Next thing you will check your variable B using print method